# What is the maximum response size in dio? (FormatException: Unterminated string)

Tags: json, flutter, dart, dio

I have an api which has more than 2MB of json data as response.

I couldn't fetch it with `GET` method of dio, because It always truncated in the middle then throws the
`FormatException: Unterminated string (at character 1622195)` Error

Any Suggestion will be appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is you are returning a String from API. So it's not about dio response size, it's about Dart String max length. As solution I would recommend following a guide on how to return util data from an API (https://jsonapi.org/). Instead of returning a String I would return a json map.